# show an image from gallery as thumbnail in titanium image view

Tags: android, ios, titanium, appcelerator-titanium

I need to display an image from the gallery as thumbnail for my project. How to display it in an imageview. Thanks in advance.  `

```
Titanium.Media.openPhotoGallery({
success : function(event) {

              //Holds the captured image
          var selectedImg= event.media;

               // Condition to check the selected media
              if(event.mediaType == Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO) {

//Define an image view with selected image from gallery
                   var imgView = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
   left       : 10,
                                   width    : 250,
   height   : 250,
   image   :  selectedImg    //Set selected image from gallery
});

//Add the image to window for displaying
myWin.add(imgView);
}
},
cancel : function() {
//While cancellation of the process
},
error : function(error) {
               // If any error occurs during the process

}
});`
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have  been trying to fetch the images from the gallery.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/railskarthi/TiMultiImagePicker You can use this module for showing image as thumbnail from the gallery